# Long poling и ограничение на запросы

Tags: php, long-poll

Есть сайт с обновлением информации в блоке, на сайте ajax навигация , информация обновляется по средствам long poling но в браузерах есть ограничение на кол-во открытых соединений и когда запущен long poling то ajax навигация перестаёт работать как бороться с этим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объединять long polling в единый запрос. Ограничение браузеров на одновременные запросы - 8 (в некоторых более старых браузерах было 4 или 16). 8 одновременных long-polling-запросов, блокирующих ajax - это явно перебор. Надо их заменить одним запросом, в ответе на который будет присылаться маркер, что же за данные пришли.

Comment: Самое интересное что открыто только 1 соединение, но пока оно открыто или пока long poling не получит ответа не происходит не 1 запрос на сайт и грузит вечно вкладку

Comment: @RedWoolf, а браузер случайно не предупреждает, что использовать синхронные ajax-запросы плохо?

Comment: Браузер нечего не говорит запрос делаю через  `$.get();` с async: true

Comment: ещё дополню слова "или пока long poling не получит ответа " ещё если даже закрыть вкладку пока не сделать рестарт сервера с убиванием apahe через диспечер (он сам не выключается), ну или же надо дать ответ лонг полингу тогда на момент ответа червер отвечает

Comment: @RedWoolf, значит у тебя на сервере выставлен лимит в одно соединение (или одно соединение на ip-адрес). Или ты там с потоками как-то не так работаешь и вешаешь сервер.

Comment: Проблема в том что используются сессии..

Comment: Решение проблемы с сессиями http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-write-close.php